# Run a remote awk command using ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, awk

I try to run a remote awk statement using ssh. My code is:

```
ssh username@hostIP "awk 'NR==1  {max=0;min=1} NR>1 {if (max<\$3) max=\$3}END {print max}' FS=\",\" /path_to_my_file"
```

When I run this command, I receive no error message, but command is not working and doesn't produce an output but just hanging so I would need to cancel it by ctrl+c.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: what is that `FS=` doing there after the `awk` command? Maybe you meant to do `awk -v FS=, '...'` instead?

Comment: janos is right, I think double quote after FS is confusing ssh whereas I used \ to escape them, but it looks it didn't work. With the format like ssh username@hostIP "awk -v FS=,  'NR==1  {max=0;min=1} NR>1 {if (max<\$3) max=\$3}END {print max}' /path_to_file " the command produced desired result. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this using a *here-doc* :

```
ssh -t username@hostIP <<'EOF'
awk '
    NR==1 {max=0;min=1}
    NR>1 {if (max<$3) max=3}
    END {print max}
' FS="," /path_to_my_file
EOF
```

The single quotes around `EOF` prevent shell expansion.

Comment: I received Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal error message.

Comment: Just a warning I think.

Comment: It worked with -t -t option. Just to force pseudo-tty allocation even if stdin isn't a terminal.

Comment: @StardustOne I am stuck with a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007951/running-awk-command-in-remote-host-fails

Comment: Thank you. I've been struggling with this.